# Meaning of subscript $n$ in sample mean variable

Tags: mean, sample, notation

I am reading Wasserman's All of Statistics. In Chapter 13: Linear and Logistic Regression, when deriving the least square estimates for simple linear regression, we have the data $(Y_1, X_1), \dots,(Y_n, X_n)$.

Wasserman denotes the sample mean of the covariates $X_i$ as $\bar{X}_n$. The sample mean for the response variable $Y$ is also denoted this way.

My question is what does the subscript $n$ mean here? Why is it not simply $\bar{X}$?

Is it to convey the number of samples used, highlighting it is a *sample* mean as opposed to a *population* mean? But isn't the population mean usually denoted by $\mu$?

Comment: I don't have the book, but might it be that they somewhere differentiate between the mean $\bar{X}_n$ calculated from the first $n$ samples and the mean (say) $\bar{X}_{n+1}$ calculated from the first $n+1$ samples?

Comment: Thanks @StephanKolassa, that could make sense. However, at least in the section I am reading, I don't see any other subscript being used aside from $n$. Maybe it is for keeping notation consistent throughout the book. 

Have you seen this sort of notation, representing the number of samples in the subscript, used elsewhere?

Comment: I can't say whether I have seen this particular convention elsewhere, but I may well have, it sounds intuitive enough.

Comment: [If you say](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106720/6460) $\bar X_n = \frac{(n-1)\bar X_{n-1}+ X_n}{n} = \bar X_{n-1} +\frac{X_n-\bar X_{n-1}}{n}$ starting with $\bar X_1 =X_1$ then you will find $\bar X_n= \frac1n (X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)$ as usual so  $\bar X_n$ is the average of the first $n$ sample values calculated from $\bar X_{n-1}$ and $X_{n}$ as the subscript of the mean changes

Comment: If you can't find the definition in the book (it should be there, somewhere, but sometimes the definitions are missing --- writing a book is hard!) then I suggest writing to the authors. There is often a preface or something that includes an address for errata and other issues. And, while I don't know Wassserman, I think most authors actually like getting politely worded mail. 

There may also be a website for the book.

Comment: "Wasserman denotes the sample mean of the covariates Xi as X¯n": doesn't that fully answer the question??

Comment: Thanks, @Henry that makes sense. However, I don't see the need for the use of the subscript in the particular section I am reading.

Comment: Thanks @PeterFlom, I will look into this.

Comment: @whuber Wasserman doesn't explicitly state this, at least in the section I am reading. I arrived at this conclusion by deriving the estimators. However, even if he did state this, my question would be as to _why_ use the subscript $n$ if there is no mention of other sample means with different number of datapoints being calculated. Is it a common convention?

Comment: But it *is* explicit!  One excellent reason for including the subscript explicitly is that when you have posited any sequence $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n,\ldots$ of random variables, then the mean depends on which prefix of the sequence it is based on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Wasserman bothers to include the $n$ subscript on $\bar X_n$ is (almost surely! ) because he uses it in other sections. For instance, see Sections 5.3 and 5.4 where the statements of the Weak Law of Large Numbers and the Central Limit Theorem depend on a *sequence* of sample means---you simply cannot define them without a sequence over $n$. He could have used $\bar X$ everywhere else and only defined $\bar X_n$ here as needed, but he must have felt it would be more consistent to use $\bar X_n$ throughout.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [Stephan Kolassa](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1352/stephan-kolassa) and [Henry](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/2958/henry) in the comments to the question, the subscript $n$ does seem to refer to the number of samples being used to calculate the mean.

In Section 3.3 "Variance and Covariance" the definition for the sample mean is given as $$\bar{X}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

Comment: $X_n$ means almost everywhere in statistics the $n$th value, usually the last of  that many values.  Here $n$ as subscript on a mean is, it seems, by way of emphasis: this mean is based on $n$ values.

Comment: @civilstat thanks for this clarification. This is the most helpful comment so far. Feel free to write it as an answer and I can accept it as the solution.